# SourceSafe Error in Visual Studio 2010 - Can't Edit File - File is already checked out by the current user in a different location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, error-handling, visual-sourcesafe

SourceSafe Related Error message I got in Visual Studio 2010 when I tried to edit a file:

```
     File is already checked out by the current user in a different location
```

Background:

- For some reason source safe saved the files 3 directories deep.
- For Example, The solution files were located in: VS2010Apps\CCP_Utility\CCP_Utility\CCP_Utility\
- The solution files should be in the root directory: VS2010Apps\CCP_Utility
- I moved the files to VS2010Apps\CCP_Utility to create this error and now I can't edit my project....

Question:

- How can I edit my files again and keep the correct directory structure???
- Do I Just delete the source safe files and re-add it to source safe or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like VSS is expecting those files in a particular directory. To solve this:

- find and make the path that VSS is expecting; the one with ccp_utility x 3.
- check-in (all files) to VSS.
- if you don't care about version history at this point, delete the project from VSS.
- disconnect/unbind your solution from version control.
- make the directory layout on disk as you need.
- drag & drop the root folder of your new layout on disk into VSS Explorer. Suggest make it a brand new path (aside your old project) in VSS, to avoid any complications.
- you now have a 'new project' as far as VSS is concerned.
- ensure your bindings are correct, and you should be able to continue as per normal.

Comment: @p.cambell, thanks for your response. I did that and it worked. I would add to the list- to backup the project as a zip file first in case any problems arise.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when my work machine was replaced and I had forgotten to check in some files on my old machine before the change.  My local copy of the file was the one I wanted to work with, but VSS had it marked as checked out on a different machine [my old machine].

I just opened the Source Safe Client, browsed to the affected files and checked them in: the client asks if I wish to proceed using the local file  (Yes) - then just reloaded the project in Visual Studio.